# When were there changes in the memory settings of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, memory

Is there a log, query or any other way to see when there was a change made to the memory settings of SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, you can see changes On SQL Log file viewer, on left panel select Windows NT to expand and select Application to display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try reading the sql server error log searching for memory configuration changes.

```
EXEC xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, "memory"
```

Example on my test machine:

[image]

[More info on xp_readerrorlog](https://www.sqlserver-dba.com/2016/03/how-to-use-xp_readerrorlog-parameters-to-search-sql-error-logs.html)